# Creating an XSD to authenticate a C# flag enumeration

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a flag enumeration of commands that can be executed

```
[Flags]
public enum Operations
{
    InstallNothing = 0,

    InstallStateDatabase = 1,
    InstallStateServer = 2,

    InstallStoreDatabase = 4,
    InstallStoreServer = 8,

    InstallMaintenanceProgram = 16,

    InstallOther=32

}

[XmlElement("Commands")]
public Operations Commands { get; set; }
```

I want to be able to read an XML file and parse it against an xsd.  I have this section of my xsd attempting to handle the validation but i don't think this is right.

```
<xs:element name="commands" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="command" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="InstallNothing" />
                <xs:enumeration value="InstallStateDatabase" />
                <xs:enumeration value="InstallStateServer" />
                <xs:enumeration value="InstallStoreDatabase" />
                <xs:enumeration value="InstallStoreServer" />
                <xs:enumeration value="InstallMaintenanceProgram" />
                <xs:enumeration value="InstallOther" />
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

The XMLs are going to be created by hand so i don't want to store the int value as the creators will not know what the int values are supposed to be.

I want my C# code to remain unchanged if possible and redesign my XSD to reflect what is supposed to be in my C# code.  Right now, some generated text XML that VS2013 generates has multiple different command elements.  I know that is how my XSD is written, but this isn't want a I want.  I want one element that has can have any of the strings in the enumeration.  How do i set up this XSD and what would an example XML look like of this implementation sending multiple different commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer(s) at 
[xsd select multiple values from enumeration or equivalent type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702629/xsd-select-multiple-values-from-enumeration-or-equivalent-type).  I wasn't searching the right thing earlier...

i added a list to my commands element.  Here is my xsd after the change:

```
<xs:element name="commands" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:list>
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="InstallNothing" />
              <xs:enumeration value="InstallStateDatabase" />
              <xs:enumeration value="InstallStateServer" />
              <xs:enumeration value="InstallStoreDatabase" />
              <xs:enumeration value="InstallStoreServer" />
              <xs:enumeration value="InstallMaintenanceProgram" />
              <xs:enumeration value="InstallOther" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:list>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
```

and an example xml using it is:

```
<commands>InstallNothing InstallStateDatabase InstallStateServer </commands>
```