# How can I unmarshal an XML document with an attribute that allows multiple enumeration values in jibx?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, unmarshalling, jibx

I want to use [Jibx](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/index.html) to unmarshal the following XML (stored in a file called test.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootElement attrWithEnum="avalue anothervalue" xsi:schemaLocation="my:target:ns simple.xsd" xmlns="my:target:ns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
</rootElement>
```

I defined the schema (in a file called simple.xsd) like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="my:target:ns" xmlns="my:target:ns" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">            
    <xs:element name="rootElement">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="attrWithEnum" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:list>
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                <xs:enumeration value="avalue"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="anothervalue"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:list>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>    
</xs:schema>
```

generated Java files from it using the `org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen` tool  and wrote this test program:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import org.jibx.runtime.BindingDirectory;
import org.jibx.runtime.IBindingFactory;
import org.jibx.runtime.IUnmarshallingContext;
import org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException;

import my.target.ns.RootElement;

public final class Program {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {                

        try {

            IBindingFactory bfact = BindingDirectory.getFactory(RootElement.class);
            IUnmarshallingContext uctx = bfact.createUnmarshallingContext();
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("test.xml"));

            RootElement data = (RootElement) uctx.unmarshalDocument(in, null);

            // This is not what I was expecting. I was expecting 
            // List<RootElement.Enumeration> (or equivalent) not
            // a single RootElement.Enumeration instance
            RootElement.Enumeration attrValue = data.getAttrWithEnum();

            System.out.println(attrValue);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This program fails with the error:

> org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: No match found for value 'avalue anothervalue' in enum class my.target.ns.RootElement$Enumeration

If I tweak my input XML like so (i.e. only set a single enum value) it works (prints `AVALUE`).

```
<rootElement attrWithEnum="avalue" xsi:schemaLocation="my:target:ns simple.xsd" xmlns="my:target:ns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

So, it seems that jibx does not like that I want to allow a list of enumeration values (I was expecting `getAttrWithEnum` to return a collection but it returns a single object - see the comment in the code example above).

The same XSD works fine when I use [jaxb](https://jaxb.java.net/) (generating the java files using [xjc](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html)), so I *think* my XSD is valid (though if there is a better way to define what I want, that would be fine).

My question therefore is:

**How can I unmarshal an XML document with an attribute that allows multiple enumeration values in jibx?**

Comment: Now that I've deleted my answer, I'll add a note here: The XML Schema is definitely correct, the list of enum values should be allowed for this attribute, and it's the best method to formulate this constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I generated a `RootElement` class with `xjc` from your schema. The field for the `attrWithEnum` attribute became `List<String> attrWithEnum` which would divide each word in the attribute as a separate string in the list. This would allow any string value, not only those defined in the enumeration.

Changing it to only `String attrWithEnum` would of course store the attribute as is.

I changed the type to an enum:

```
enum AttrEnum {
    avalue,
    anothervalue
}
@XmlAttribute(name = "attrWithEnum", required = true)
public List<AttrEnum> attrWithEnum;
```

Using JAXB (I've never used Jibx) this gives me a list of only valid values. Any value in the attribute that is not defined in the enumeration is returned as a `null` value.

Changing the field to `AttrEnum attrWithEnum` would only return a non-null value if the attribute only contains *one* valid value from the enumeration.

*So my guess is that your `RootElement` class defines `attrWithEnum` as a single `enum` instead of as a list of enum (`List<AttrEnum>`)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have the enumeration inside a list, so I think the schema does permit it - see for example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702629/xsd-select-multiple-values-from-enumeration-or-equivalent-type

Comment: You're right. It should be possible. What does your `RootElement` class look like?

Comment: I've edited my answer and given an educated guess on what the problem might be.

Comment: Yes, jibx is defining that property as a single object, not a collection (I tried to say this in a bracket in my question - I guess I should have spelled it out better - I'll update the question).  A List<String> would be better as schema validation would ensure that the string is valid within the restriction (as long as I validate the schema).  So I could, in that case, convert to an enum from the string safely.  I also tried jaxb and had better results, but I want to give jibx a chance as I am finding jaxb performance to be poor (but it seems to understand the schema better).